# Django - Where to create classes to manipulate database

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Where i must create classes in order to manipulate data of the database?
I have 4 app in my project. Can i create an app specially for that, and create all the classes/functions in the models.py ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better approach is to have each app its own `models.py`. which would define the database tables each app is using.

And to have each app its own `views.py`. which would define the logic of the app and manipulation of the data of your database.

I don't think you really understand what apps really are in Django and you can learn about them in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350785/what-s-the-difference-between-a-project-and-an-app-in-django-world/54490497#54490497) look at other answer and mine too.

Comment: i read it, thx. For the app Car/, where can i create a new class with constructor and new functions to manipulate data of the class Car witch is define in the models.py ?

Comment: Thank you. In this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350785/what-s-the-difference-between-a-project-and-an-app-in-django-world/54490497#54490497) i can not tcheck it because it's already tcheked by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's recommended to create your models in each of your apps directory for [reusability](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/).

edit* check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49736970/8001439) if you're wondering how to implement singleton in django,

Comment: Yes thank you, that's what i did. But i'd like to know where to create class ofr functions to pass queries. For exemple, i have two app: Student, Teacher. If i have a query wich join two tables of those apps, in what model that i will create a function for manipulate data?

Comment: Oh i see, you can checkout [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) in that case, it's bascically a join query

Comment: Okey thx; Is it in the models.py that i must create fucntions or othern classes to maque queries ?

Comment: Your models represent classes and as well as tables of database.

Comment: QTcho, functions you can create everywhere you like. Python is very flexible language, and Django is just a python code, although quite big project. There's no restrictions how you can structure your code. So you can create functions in convenient places accordingly to your application structure and `import` them where necessary. One detail is that django has some "common" approaches for queries, like `QuerSet` objects or `Manager` classes. You may probably like to use them too